# How to select a particular record without using OR condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

```
Item_Code   |Item_Description        |EAN Code      |Price   |Company_Code| Unit|
------------+------------------------+--------------+--------+------------+-----+
S-035-ED-TU |TCCA 35ml Everyday (100)|0000093507752 |4.220000|SKH         |EACH      
S-035-ED-TU |TCCA 35ml Everyday (100)|10000093507759|4.220000|SKH         |SHIPPER  
S-035-ED-TU |TCCA 35ml Everyday (100)|10000093507759|4.220000|SKH         |INNER   
S-050-PP-50P|TCCA 50ml Kids Peppa Pig|10000093545324|9.500000|SKH         |SHIPPER
```

Question - For some item codes there is only 1 Unit (Shipper) available but for some item codes there are 2 or 3 Unit codes are there (Each, Shipper,INNER) as in above example.

I want to use a query that if there are multiple unit_codes for a particular item in a table then select "Each" else select '`Shipper`' or '`EACH`' or '`INNER`' whatever is available.

Thanks
Tushar

Comment: Why are you against using `OR`?

Comment: **need to know which database** you are using. "sql" is a language standard but each database has different syntax implementations of it (eg: MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle ...?)

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: @user9096211 Then add SQL Server tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is 2 solutions in SQL Server.. The second i think is better

```
CREATE TABLE #test (
    item_code NVARCHAR(1000),
    item_description NVARCHAR(1000),
    ean_code NVARCHAR(1000),
    price NVARCHAR(1000),
    campany_code NVARCHAR(1000),
    unit NVARCHAR(1000),
    )

INSERT INTO #test (
    item_code,
    item_description,
    ean_code,
    price,
    campany_code,
    unit
    )
VALUES (
    'S-035-ED-TU',
    'TCCA 35ml Everyday (100)',
    '0000093507752',
    '4.220000',
    'SKH',
    'EACH'
    ),
    (
    'S-035-ED-TU',
    'TCCA 35ml Everyday (100)',
    '0000093507752',
    '4.220000',
    'SKH',
    'SHIPPER'
    ),
    (
    'S-035-ED-TU',
    'TCCA 35ml Everyday (100)',
    '0000093507752',
    '4.220000',
    'SKH',
    'INNER'
    ),
    (
    'S-050-PP-50P',
    'TCCA 50ml Kids Peppa Pig',
    '10000093545324',
    '9.500000',
    'SKH',
    'SHIPPER'
    )

--Get all records just to see
SELECT *
FROM #test

--METHOD 1: One way you could do it
SELECT *
FROM #test t
WHERE unit = CASE 
        WHEN (
                SELECT count(*)
                FROM #test t2
                WHERE t.item_code = t2.item_code
                ) > 1
            THEN 'EACH'
        ELSE unit
        END

--METHOD 2: Maybe a better way to do it using a temp table
SELECT t.item_code,
    count(*) RecordsPerGroup
INTO #itemCodeCount
FROM #test t
GROUP BY item_code

SELECT t.*
FROM #test t
LEFT JOIN #itemCodeCount icc
    ON t.item_code = icc.item_code
WHERE t.unit = CASE 
        WHEN icc.RecordsPerGroup > 1
            THEN 'EACH'
        ELSE t.unit
        END

DROP TABLE #test

DROP TABLE #itemCodeCount
```

Comment: Hi Austin, Thanks for your reply. Have 1 question about t2, you have renamed the Test Table to t2 in where clause right? or where it came  from?

Comment: it's just an inner select inside of a select so you have to give tables an alias which is `t` and `t2`

Answer (score 0):

For databases that support "window functions" this may do what you are seeking:

```
SELECT
      d.*
FROM (
      SELECT
            t.*
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item_Code
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN Unit = 'EACH' THEN 1 
                          WHEN unint = 'SHIPPER' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END) AS unit_pref
      FROM yourtable t
      ) d
WHERE d.unit_pref = 1
```

nb: MySQL (currently 5.7) does not (yet) support "window functions", but will do that in version 8

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    create table #tmp(Item_Code VARCHAR(50),EAN_Code VARCHAR(100),Unit VARCHAR(10))



    insert into #tmp VALUES('S-035-ED-TU','10000093507759','SHIPPER')
    insert into #tmp VALUES('S-035-ED-TU','10000093507759','INNER')
    insert into #tmp VALUES('S-035-ED-TU','0000093507752','EACH')

    insert into #tmp VALUES('S-050-PP-50P','10000093545324','SHIPPER')


    select Item_Code 
    into #tmpMultiUnit
    from #tmp 
    Group by Item_Code
    Having Count(Unit)>1

    SELECT t.* from #tmp t
    LEFT JOIN #tmpMultiUnit tm on t.Item_Code=tm.Item_Code
    WHERE tm.Item_Code IS NULL OR t.Unit='EACH'

    Drop table #tmp

    DRop table #tmpMultiUnit
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's three (3) years late but just in case someone has the same question, here's my contribution.

Using the columns from your illustration, I needed to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    Item_Code NVARCHAR(100),
    Item_Description NVARCHAR(100),
    EAN_Code VARCHAR(100),
    Price DECIMAL(22,6),
    Company_Code NVARCHAR(50),
    Unit VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('S-035-ED-TU','TCCA 35ml Everyday (100)', '10000093507759', 4.220000, 'SKH' ,'EACH')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('S-035-ED-TU','TCCA 35ml Everyday (100)', '10000093507759', 4.220000, 'SKH' ,'SHIPPER')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('S-035-ED-TU','TCCA 35ml Everyday (100)', '10000093507759', 4.220000, 'SKH' ,'INNER')
insert into #tmp VALUES('S-050-PP-50P','TCCA 50ml Kids Peppa Pig', '10000093545324', 9.500000, 'SKH', 'SHIPPER')
```

Then, the query can be expressed like this:

```
SELECT t.Item_Code, t.Item_Description, t.EAN_Code, t.Price, t.Company_Code, 
        CASE WHEN uom.Count > 1 THEN 'EACH' ELSE t.Unit END AS Unit,
        t.Unit AS [(OriginalUnit)]
FROM #tmp t
    INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS Count, Item_Code FROM #tmp GROUP BY Item_Code) uom ON t.Item_Code = uom.Item_Code
```

Which results in:

[image: Query result 1]

Now, this query would not be versatile whenever a new unit of measure equivalent to `EACH` is desired to appear as the query has been hard-coded to display `EACH` whenever a multiple unit of an item code is encountered. There must be a basis to select the unit from the multitude. I have taken the liberty to modify the table by adding a `Conversion` column to serve as an indicator.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    Item_Code NVARCHAR(100),
    Item_Description NVARCHAR(100),
    EAN_Code VARCHAR(100),
    Price DECIMAL(22,6),
    Company_Code NVARCHAR(50),
    Unit VARCHAR(10),
    Conversion float /* Added to automatically select which ever has the lowest conversion */
)

INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('S-035-ED-TU','TCCA 35ml Everyday (100)', '10000093507759', 4.220000, 'SKH' ,'EACH', 1)    
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('S-035-ED-TU','TCCA 35ml Everyday (100)', '10000093507759', 4.220000, 'SKH' ,'INNER', 4)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('S-035-ED-TU','TCCA 35ml Everyday (100)', '10000093507759', 4.220000, 'SKH' ,'SHIPPER', 24)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('S-050-PP-50P','TCCA 50ml Kids Peppa Pig', '10000093545324', 9.500000, 'SKH', 'SHIPPER', 1)
```

Then we have just to find the unit that has the lowest conversion:

```
SELECT t.Item_Code, t.Item_Description, t.EAN_Code, t.Price, t.Company_Code, 
        CASE WHEN uom.NumUnit > 1 THEN uom.Unit ELSE t.Unit END AS Unit,
        t.Unit AS [(OriginalUnit)]
FROM #tmp t
    INNER JOIN (SELECT t2.NumUnit, t1.Item_Code, t1.Unit 
                FROM #tmp t1
                    INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS NumUnit, Item_Code, MIN(Conversion) AS Conversion
                                FROM #tmp       
                                GROUP BY Item_Code) t2 ON t1.Item_Code = t2.Item_Code AND t1.Conversion = t2.Conversion) uom ON t.Item_Code = uom.Item_Code
```

Which produces the same result, but the `EACH` was not hard-coded:

[image: Query 2]

To verify whether the joined sub-query has choosen correctly, extract it from the main query and run:

```
SELECT t2.NumUnit, t1.Item_Code, t1.Unit 
FROM #tmp t1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS NumUnit, Item_Code, MIN(Conversion) AS Conversion
                FROM #tmp       
                GROUP BY Item_Code) t2 ON t1.Item_Code = t2.Item_Code AND t1.Conversion = t2.Conversion
```

The result:

[image: Query 3]